# Could not find file "System.Net.ConnectStream" after downgrading to .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on creating a SQL CLR stored procedure for geocoding addresses, via the Google Maps API.  The version of SQL I'm using is 2008, which only supports .NET 3.5 and below, hence the need for me to downgrade my target framework.

I'm currently generating a web request, getting its response, and then attempting to get its response stream with the following code:

```
 var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
 var response = request.GetResponse();
 var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream().ToString());
```

I'm using the ToString() method on the last line, because the XDocument.Load() method doesn't support streams in .NET 3.5.

It's that last line where I get the following exception, which I have yet to resolve:

> Could not find file 'c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\GoogleGeoCoder\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\System.Net.ConnectStream'.

Bear in mind that all of this worked great when targeting .NET 4--the only adjustment was adding the ToString() method.

Any ideas on how to resolve the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.GetResponseStream()` returns a `Stream`. When you `.ToString()` a `Stream` you're going to get the name of the class, not the contents of the stream.

If you want to get the contents of the stream you'll need to read the stream first.

```
var response = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.ReadToEnd().ToString());
```

Comment: You should use `using` blocks. When you fix that, I'll +1: `using (var response = request.GetResponse()) using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream()) using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) XDocument.Load(reader.ReadToEnd());`

Comment: Thanks, Craig.  I had to switch it to XDocument.Parse(), but other than that, your suggestion worked great.

`var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
var response = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(re sponse.ReadToEnd().ToString());`